# First Instance of "STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE" Identifier is Undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console, std

I am using Visual Studio 2019, and my code uses console outputs which change colors frequently. I am including `Windows.h` in my code, which is the header file that contains `SetConsoleTextAttributes`, whereas `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` should be initialized by `using namespace std`. My code in its entirety can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/5fCGwmzR), but the following is the section with the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "HeadFile.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int Play(char(&spaces)[7][6], int(&color)[7][6], int player, int playerOneWins, int playerTwoWins, int ties)
{
    HANDLE hConsole;
    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
.....
```

***The code runs fine***, but inside of studio itself, I see the following error:

[image]

The error is coming from the ***first instance*** of `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` **only** (another case at the bottom of the picture has no errors). If I comment out the first one, the next instance errors:

[image]

How can I fix this issue? I've read in a few non-related posts that `using namespace std` can sometimes lead to problems. Is this the case?

Comment: `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` is a preprocessor macro, it is not affected by `using namespace std;` (which [you should not be using to begin with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)) . What you describe is an IDE issue, not a coding issue.

Comment: Code analysis tools have to balance accurate and fast, and sometimes fast wins and the tool spits out a false positive. Wish I had a solution for you, but instead all I can do is share the pain. I have rewritten valid code to eliminate bogus warning more than once.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good to know, I'll see if there's anything I can do from VS

Comment: @user4581301 I'll keep that in mind, thanks. I've had that happen before in Eclipse but never VS

Comment: Don't get me started on Eclipse. Chokes on forward-declarations of nested classes, and I have a LOT of of those suckers serving up PIMPLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Header file "Windows.h" instead of "windows.h".

Comment: So you think that capitalisation of file names is the problem in a windows environment. Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes since the C++ and a lot of other languages are case sensitive, the names need to be written exactly the same.

Comment: Muneeb Elahi Malik thanks for your extremely concise answer! @MehrozMustafa It is good to know that C++ library names are case sensitive!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, adding `#include <stdlib.h>` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you need to use #include <Stdio.h>

Comment: There is no such standard GCC library named as Stdio.h. I think you are referring the one with small s?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33406064)